# How to get @keyframes animation in Safari to work like in Chrome/FF?

Tags: css, animation

I'm having issues with @keyframes in Safari. I thought the issue was short-hand or combining multiple animations into one animation property: `-webkit-animation-name: anim1, anim2, anim3`. Didn't matter. I looked around and I think using percentage wrong is the issue, like it needs a middle point, 50%, to get rotate3d to work.

When I have just 0% and 100%, rotate3d allows the DIV to spin all the way around in Chrome/FF. In Safari, there was no movement. Thus, I added 50% and it now moves, but it doesn't spin all the way around. Not sure what to do without adding a bunch more percentages. What am I missing?

```
<div>
    <p>hello</p>
</div>


div {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;

  /* -webkit-animation: 3s spin infinite;
   animation: 3s spin infinite;
   */

  -webkit-animation-name: spin;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 2, 1, 0deg);
  }
  /*   Works somewhat if I add 50% {..},  
  but it doesn't go all the way around like in Chrome and FF */
/*   50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 2, 1, 180deg);
  } */
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 2, 1, 360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(1, 2, 1, 0deg);
  }
/*   50% {
    transform: rotate3d(1, 2, 1, 180deg);
  } */
  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(1, 2, 1, 360deg);
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j9payfkg/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. I stripped out the other code just for easy viewing of code.

In short you did not give a full percentage value as the spin does not end at 360 but rather 0. So you need 4 keyframes.

**Keep in mind that this is for Safari and I did not add the FF and Chrome in this code. So please view in Safari.**

0deg > 2 intermediaries and back to > 0deg

```css
div {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
  
 -webkit-animation-name: spin;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;

}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 2, 1, 0deg);
  }
    25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 2, 1, 90deg);
  }
    50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 2, 1, 180deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 2, 1, 0deg);

}
```

```html
  <div>
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
```